# How to run VLC (with stream) inside android app?

Tags: android, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, android-studio

I want to run vlc with a network stream (http://mumsite.cdnsrv.jio.com/jiotv.live.cdn.jio.com/Aaj_Tak/Aaj_Tak_800.m3u8)
with `libvlc`.

I want to run VLC because I can't get play it using `hls.js`, `flashls` or any other web based streaming.

VLC is fine for me on both PC and Android.

Possible solution:-

> 1. Run VLC with network stream from my app.
> 2. Run VLC inside app with stream.

Any help Please, I am a noob.

Comment: How did you find that link? From JIO TV App? Astonished! I open that link in Google Chrome in Android and Chrome start to play it. Otherwise any browser downloads a .m3u8 file (can be opened in any text editor).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my device (android 6) can play that link on mxplayer and on chrome..
so if overall goal here is to watch news then you can install mxplayer, 
tap on that link to open in MX player,This plays perfectly fine !!

or Open it directly in chrome ,tap on triangular button ,thats it.
BTW you did not provided android version but I tested this on Android 6.

done...